# TestNg, annotation "beforeTestMethod" and override

Tags: java, testng

For my tests I'm using a base class `MyTestBase` defining a method `setup()` that does some base preparations:

```
public class MyTestBase {
    @Configuration( beforeTestMethod=true )
    protected void setup() {
        // do base preparations
    }
}
```

Now I have some more specific test classes that have to do their own preparations. There are different ways how to implement this.

I could use `@Override`:

```
public class MySpecialTestBase extends MyTestBase {
    @Override
    protected void setup() {
        super.setup();
        // do additional preparations
    }
}
```

...or I could use a separate setup method:

```
public class MySpecialTestBase extends MyTestBase {
    @Configuration( beforeTestMethod=true )
    protected void setupSpecial() {
        // do additional preparations
    }
}
```

**Is there a prefered way to implement this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer using `@Configuration` annotation. `@Override` and `super` are more fragile. You can  forget to call `super.setup()`, or call it in wrong place. Meanwhile, using separate method with `@Configuration` lets you to choose more appropriate naming for child setup method if necessary, and you get setup order guaranteed by TestNG (parent then child).

Two more points:

1. I'd make parent setup `final` in order to forbid accidental overriding.
2. I'd use `@BeforeMethod` annotations. They are available since TestNG 5.0. Of course, for older versions you forced to using `@Configuration`.