# In TestNG is there a way to run a cleanup method only after a particular test method?

Tags: testng

One example: after a password change test executes I would like to a cleanup method to reset the password back to the original password. Annotating the cleanup method with @AfterGroups and making the test method as the only method in a group is one way but it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2):

This question might provide some help: [TestNg, annotation "beforeTestMethod" and override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559343/testng-annotation-beforetestmethod-and-override).  It's a very similar question, but with customizing the @BeforeMethod instead of the cleanup (@AfterMethod).  Essentially, you could create a base test class, and have a child test class that contains all the methods requiring password reset, and which supplies it's own @AfterMethod.  This may or may not be a logical choice in your situation, depending on your tests, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is exactly how I would implement such a functionality, sorry it doesn't feel right to you :-)

How would you prefer to do this?

Comment: I would like a cleanup method that would run immediately after another method and would not depend on the first method succeeding. Another ask would be for the cleanup method to run immediately after 2 or more methods ran. Such that methodA runs and then the cleanup method runs and later after methodD runs then the cleanup method runs again. With the @AfterGroups annotation the cleanup method would only be run once after all the methods in the group ran. I would like the cleanup method to run after each method that needs it has run.

Comment: This is a bit of a contrived scenario, but maybe you could use a custom annotation for this.  Here is how this could work:

http://beust.com/weblog/2010/03/23/better-mock-testing-with-testng/